# Append folder to all view paths

Tags: laravel, view

Is there a simple way to append a folder name to ALL executed view paths?

For example, let's say I have a config value for `app.template` called `default` which represents the name of the folder I want to load my views from. This would be for a simple templating system where changing all views is super easy.

How could I prepend `default.` to all loaded views via `config()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `config/view.php` you can set the directories which view files are resolved from:

```
'paths' => [ 
     __DIR__.'/../views', 
     __DIR__.'/../default/views 
],
```

Alternatively, you can use the `addLocation` method:

```
View::addLocation(app_path() . 'default/views');
```